# Using 6S lithium-ion battery with(out) bms?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, bms

I built a 6S LTO battery pack and I am wondering - does it need BMS? Battery will be charged with car alternator - voltage wont exceed passive BMS balancing threshold (battery will never reach maximum voltage), thus balancing wont even happen. Is it safe to use battery like that? Or do I need to use active balancing, which, as I understand, balance all the time, at any voltage?

Comment: Charged by alternator? Is there a lithium battery charger between alternator and battery pack, or just alternator connectd to a battery pack?

Comment: I'll use charger with up to 16V output

Comment: 6S LTO BMS is readily available and pretty cheap : why wouldn't you want to use one?

Comment: As I said - voltage wont reach maximum, so passive BMS wont even balance them. Unless I use active BMS. But question remains - are BMS'es necessary?

Comment: choose PCM with equilibrium function to keep each cell in balance and good service life, But a good BMS is best for longer life.  How well matched do you think these electrolytics are? Are you familiar with the exponential divergence?

Comment: Where did you get the cells from?

Answer (score 1):

> does it need BMS?

You **always** need a BMS for any Li-ion battery, LTO and any other chemistry. **Never** operate Li-ion cells without protection: it's at best dangerous for the cells, and and worst dangerous for people and property.

> Battery will be charged with car alternator

**Never** charge a Li-ion battery directly from an alternator that is not current limited (and most alternators aren't). Always use a charger (a current limiting and voltage regulating circuit) between the alternator and the Li-ion battery. If you don't, it damages the battery and overheats the alternator.

> thus balancing wont even happen

Well, that's up to you. Just know that the effective battery capacity will go down faster as the cells get our of balance.

> Is it safe to use battery like that?

Absolutely not!

> Or do I need to use active balancing

You don't. (Most applications don't.)

> , which, as I understand, balance all the time, at any voltage?

No, that's not what "active balancing" is. That would be "SoC based" balancing.